# Is this an even or odd element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So I [saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679003/jquery-tigerstipe-rollover-conundrum) a few moments ago on SO and it got me thinking.

Basically the OP had something along these lines

```
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
```

```
$('div').each( function() {
   //do something different based on whether even or odd div
   if ($(this) == ':even') {}  //invalid markup I know!
   else {}
});
```

**Is there a way to tell inside the `.each()` whether your current element is an odd or even instance?**

There is the `.filter` method of jQuery, but it always returns true when it has a single element.

I also realize you can use the nth-child selector or set this up in other ways, but I am curious about this specific case.

Comment: It's already in the answer to that question. Take a look at the last code snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679003/jquery-tigerstipe-rollover-conundrum/7679027#7679027

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks, I missed that update.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The callback to [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is passed the element's index and the element:

```
$('div').each(function(i, el) {
   // As a side note, this === el.
   if (i % 2 === 0) { /* we are even */ }
   else { /* we are odd */ }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize it had a callback for index! http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/EjduK/

Answer (score 9):

```
$('div').each( function(index) {
   //do something different based on whether even or odd div
   if (index % 2 == 0) {}  // even
   else {} // odd
});
```

Comment: actually both of u have same time :)

Answer (score 6):

If you know that all of the elements are children of the same parent, you can use the index provided by each

```
$('div').each( function(index) {
    if (index%2 == 0) {}
    else {}
});
```

otherwise, use the [index](http://api.jquery.com) function which will calculate the index of the element among its siblings.

```
$('div').each( function() {
    if ($(this).index()%2 == 0) {}
    else {}
});
```

Comment: +1 - thanks for showing me the .index() method. A new one for me!

Answer (score 3):

Using Jquery api [.is( selector )](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$('div').each( function() {
    //Check if element is even
    if ($(this).is(":even")) {
    }

    //Check if element is odd
    if ($(this).is(":odd")) {
    }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Another user proffered the same solution and has since deleted the answer. Logically it does look promising, but doesn't pan out. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/EjduK/1/

Comment: @mrtsherman: Thanks and yes, i have checked again and found it doesn't work for jquery version < 1.10.1. You have jquery 1.6.3 in your jsfiddle link.