# alternating between even and odd elements in json with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to generate a .html div containers using .json file that looks like below.

```
[
{
"KEYWORD": XXXX,
            "DATEx": XXXX,
            "TOPIC": XXXX,
            "CSPANLINK": XXXX,
            "EXCERPTS": XXXX
    },
    {
            "KEYWORD": YYYY,
            "DATEx": YYYY,
            "TOPIC": YYYY,
            "CSPANLINK": YYYY,
            "EXCERPTS": YYYY
}]
```

For odd numbered elements, I want to create div with class = "container left" and for even numbered elements, I want to create div with class = "container right". I used the below code to generate .html:

```
$.getJSON("XXXXYYYY.json", function (data) {
    var html = '';
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        html += '<div class="container left">';
        html += '<div class="content">';
        html += '<h2>' + value.DATEx + '</h2>'
        html += '<p>' + value.EXCERPTS + '</p>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
    });
    
    $('div.timeline').html(html);
});
```

So in a nutshell, I would like to alternate between these two codes, depending on the index of each element.

```
html += '<div class="container left">';
```

and

```
html += '<div class="container right">';
```

What kind of javascript conditional statement should I use to do this?

Comment: It seems like the modulo operator would help you in figuring out if the div is odd or even. your key value in the loop should be the current number. This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016313/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-odd-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you pass in the `$.each` is the array and the function callback with `index` and `value`

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

So in your case you can check even odd for your index and add the class accordingly.

Something like this

```
$.getJSON("XXXXYYYY.json", function (data) {
    var html = '';
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        html += index%2===0 ? '<div class="container right">' : '<div class="container left">';
        html += '<div class="content">';
        html += '<h2>' + value.DATEx + '</h2>'
        html += '<p>' + value.EXCERPTS + '</p>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
    });
    
    $('div.timeline').html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like its an duplication of:
**[Is this an even or odd element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679446/is-this-an-even-or-odd-element)**

Therefor the following Code should work for you.

```
$('div').each(function(i, el) {
   // As a side note, this === el.
   if (i % 2 === 0) { /* we are even */ }
   else { /* we are odd */ }
});
```